# Joomla GEOIP Maxmind redirect loop

Tags: php, redirect, joomla2.5, geoip

I'm trying to implement the Geoip service on my joomla 2.5 installation.

What I want is that the website http://www.example.com redirects to http://www.example.com/fr for the france language.

I've included the maxmind geoip in the header of the template file. But the redirect executes in a loop.

This is how I execute the file:

```
<?php include_once('templates/my_template/geoip/country-redirect.php'); ?>
```

This is my redirect script:

```
$gi = geoip_open('templates/my_template/geoip/GeoIP.dat', GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
$country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
// prints the country code  your visitor is in
if($country == 'FR')
{
header('Location: http://www.example.com/fr');
exit();
}
else if($country == 'US')
{
header('Location: http://example.com');
exit();
}
// the end
geoip_close($gi);
```

I think because the script is executed from the template it will execute every time the template file is loaded, so on a redirect it will continiously execute this script.

Comment: If /fr or most likely us (example.com) has the same script, check your current position before redirecting or you will redirect forever...

Comment: Do you have an example script for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $addr = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].dirname( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
   $fr = (($addr == 'www.example.com/fr')||($addr == 'example.com/fr'));
   if((!$fr)&&($country == 'FR')){ // if not at france and country is france
     header('Location: http://www.example.com/fr');
     exit(); // you exit here, so no else required
   }
   if(($fr)&&($country == 'US')){ // if at france and country is US
     header('Location: http://example.com');
     exit();
   }
```

Note that this script is assumed to run at www.example.com/ and www.example.com/fr/ directories

Comment: It stays in a loop, argh. So the browser says that it has to many connections. And the page does not load. The script needs to check if the script is already executed.

Comment: Sorry can you at least echo the addr? lets check it.